# Object detection mAP scores is too high on test data

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have trained multiple deep learning object detection models on my own custom dataset of beef cattle. I am planning to compare the performance of the models between them and YOLO Version 3. To do so, I am using legacy/eval.py to get the mAP of the trained model. I have tried to get the mAP for Faster-RCNN ResNet-50 at this moment by running the following codes -

```
python legacy/eval.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_resnet50.config checkpoint_dir=training/ --eval_dir=eval/
```

After running the evaluation on the test dataset, it is showing mAP as >0.99 which is way too high. The same model gained ~0.3 on the COCO dataset. Is it normal to have such a high mAP while evaluating on training dataset?

My system is as follows-

```
python 3.6
tensorflow 1.5 (gpu)
number of training image ~2800
number of test image ~400
evaluated on test image
```